# How to get the default homepage from the default browser

Tags: c#

how can i get the default homepage from the default browser (IE, firefox,...) in C#.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a desktop APP or a web APP?  A desktop app can look in the registry for some information, a web app is a lot more tricky (IE: ActiveX control or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no universal way to do it. First, you'd need to find the default browser. The path to the EXE for the default browser is always stored in the registry key:

> HKCR\HTTP\shell\open\command

Once you know the browser, things are a lot more open-ended. Internet Explorer, for example, stores the home page URL in the following registry key:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page

In general however, browser can store the home page in any way they like (possibly in the registry but, possibly in a config file).

Note: If you're not familiar with accessing the Windows registry in .NET/C#, [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) should provide all the info you need.

Comment: Tks, thats is what i trying to do. I have the default browser. now is the second step, search for each browser the homepage.

Comment: While assuming Luis is on windows is probably right in this case, the answer is OS dependent.

Comment: @Jason: Technically, yes. It's usually pretty safe to assume someone is using MS.NET when they don't specify Mono though.

Comment: in the MAC OS, is possible to do it? with c#?

Comment: So you are using Mono? Sure it would be, I just don't know the specifics for Mac. :)