# Access registry from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, registry

Is it possible to access to the registry from a web application?

Comment: Which registry? The client's or the server's?

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747085/how-to-get-the-default-homepage-from-the-default-browser), the client's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading you comment to @SLaks I'm inclined to point out that there are server tools that are there to do exactly that.

In fact I think Windows Server editions come with these features out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely impossible to access the end-users registry, unless you use an IE-only ActiveX control.   (and there is (almost) no better way to make your users hate you than to use an ActiveX control)

If you're [trying to check your end-users' home pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747085/how-to-get-the-default-homepage-from-the-default-browser), you should give up; it's completely impossible.

Comment: Its a intranet website, and i wanna check if the computers have the default homepage (company website) and the company wallpaper. So what i was thinking was, every time they access the intranet website, check this stuff. Its possible to use the computer name, and do a remote access to the registry?

Comment: That's an incredibly stupid thing to do.  **Let your employees change their home page!** It may make them (a little bit) more productive, and it will make them hate you less.

Comment: i'm not the boss :/ .. just orders :s

Answer (score 1):

The registry, as in the Windows registry? It might be possible with Internet Explorer 6, but I don't think so. There's no possible (good) reason to access the registry on a website, you just don't want that!

Comment: +1, God that would be a bad idea.  If the aim of this is to store information then consider an xml file or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the client's, then no. (It might be with some ActiveX controls, but I am not sure on that)

Why do you need to be accessing the registry from a webapp anyway?

Comment: I gonna coment in this one. Its a intranet website, and i wanna check if the computers have the default homepage (company website) and the company website. So what i was thinking was, every time they access the intranet website, check this stuff. Its possible to use the computer name, and do a remote access to the registry?

Comment: From the domain controller, yes I believe you can use something like Regsrvr32 or something like that. But I don't know how to pragmatically access it.

Also: If it is an intranet site, why not just use a domain policy to force the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the client's registry no, you could access the registry on the server but that would be a fairly iffy thing todo in a web app.