# How to change registry settings on a system through web browser

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am trying to develop a web page that will allow user to edit registry settings in windows system. Can i achieve it with client side scripting language.?  If yes please suggest me language to do.
Can we do it with jQuery or any other type of library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to obvious security concerns, this is only possible in Internet Explorer(!). This is not a jQuery library, but an activeX control; so it's quite unpleasant to use.

You have been warned, so here is the documentation :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156602.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately is impossible to access the registry from a web app: the only way you have is through an ActiveX control but I would not go down this road.

have a look at the below

[Access registry from a web aplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829826/access-registry-from-a-web-aplication)

Answer (score 0):

Far from ideal but ...

If you serve up a ".hta" file (HTml Application) from your web server, Windows will run it as a program outside of IE and give it the privileges of the PC user. It will be in a separate window and there won't be any browser features (Back/Refresh/Address bar etc).

Even then, modern versions of Windows will prompt the user with security warnings if a HTA is launched from anywhere other than a local drive.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I am not sure I like any answers for this problem.  Instead of trying to access the Registry directly through Javascript, try writing a Java Applet and talk to the java applet using Javascript.  Then in the JavaApplet you can write some JNI code to write a native dll to do what you need.  It isn't a direct solution to your problem, but it will allow you to do what you need across multiple browsers.  The downside is that you can't use it on browsers that do not support running a Java Applet, such as a mobile platform.

This method will also require you to sign your Java Applet.  This is how you get around the security issues.  The user will have to accept the applet the first time to give the security access.