# How to insert reg key strings into html?

Tags: html, string, insert, registry

how to add reg key or strings into html code page ?

I would like to insert the key strings into html such :

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

so how to insert this one into html code ?!

Comment: like this: `<p>HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run</p>` :) Now seriously folks, you can no more access the registry from your browser than you can access the contents of your local disks, and the reasons why should be rather obvious.

Comment: no , actually i asked for that to know how to add the key using html with out using reg file .

Comment: @user3182858 - Do you just want to **show** the text in the HTML or do you want to **edit** the windows registry from an HTML page? Editing the registry with HTML is not possible.

Comment: mm , but if i tried to add the key using vbs and then insert vbs code into html that would be fine except the Active x , so i`v tried to think how to add reg key using browser

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773124/how-to-change-registry-settings-on-a-system-through-web-browser

Possible badly worded duplicate?